# What does "->" mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does the **->** operator do in the .js code below?

```
_blm.mpU_onIdentified(function() {
        console.log('find_program_result.js -> mpU_onIdentified');
        _blm.mpU.people.set({
                'findProgramsResultsHref': location.href
        });
```

Comment: Nothing, thats text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't an operator - it's inside a string which is being logged. You can identify it by the quotes enclosing it:

```
console.log('find_program_result.js -> mpU_onIdentified');
// quotes --^------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: you got 9 up votes for this? really?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly yeah its kinda weird how a really simple basic level answer can get that many upvotes while some really high quality answers are struggling to get upvotes